# Python plotting months on x-axis get overlap for a longer period

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts

I am stuck while plotting a data with months on the x-axis and the period for the date is huge (i.e, all months from the year 2000 till 2017). Here is my output.
[image]

My dataframe looks like,

```
Date        Count
2001-05-31  2   
2001-06-30  0   
2001-07-31  0   
2001-08-31  6   
2001-09-30  1
    .       .
    .       .
    .       .
2017-12-31  12
```

I searched a lot but didn't get something useful, so what should I do to make it more visible or should I go for other plots and how?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to plot periods only for example label only every a month or 6-months like 12/2002-01/2003 and use only ticks for specific dates. I think is not possible to make all these data labels visible.

Comment: ok, that's sound good for this situation but can I try some other plots so that I can show all months for all year.